# Inclusion Exclusion Principle for Set Theory in Paul Sally

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $B$ are finite sets and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, show that $\mathbf{card}(A\cup B) = \mathbf{card}(A)+\mathbf{card}(B)$

I understand why this is true, but if someone could give me directions on how to start this proof, it would be helpful. For context, this comes from Paul Sally's *Tools of the Trade*, if that makes a difference

Comment: I do not know what proof is expected, the result is clear by drawing a picture (Venn diagram). It is conceivable that you are expected to use $\text{card}(A\cup B)=\text{card}(A)+\text{card}(B)-\text{card}(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it

Comment: If u want only direction than, u could prove it by contradiction. Did u ever prove that 2 under of root is irrational its somethink like this

Comment: How you prove it depends on what set theory axioms you are using, etc. Intuitively, you can prove it for finite sets by induction, if you know it just for the case $B=\{*\}$, a single element. In more advanced set theory, this is practically the definition of sum of cardinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{card}(A)=m$ and $\mathbf{card}(B)=n$. Then there are one-to-one and onto maps: $$f:\{1,2,\dots,m\}\to A\\
g:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to B$$

Define $h:\{1,2,\dots,n+m\}\to A\cup B$ as:

$$h(k)=\begin{cases}f(n)&k\leq m\\
g(k-n)&k>m
\end{cases}$$

Show that $h$ is onto $A\cup B$, and if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $h$ is one-to-one.

Comment: 1−1, I dont understand this part might u explain it with a little bit more information

Comment: I shouldn't have used the abbreviation. It is short for "one-to-one." If you don't know the terms "one-to-one" and "onto," then you aren't going to get much out of this approach.

Comment: I study math with russian language and I not good with english

Comment: A function is "one-to-one" if, when $f(a)=f(c)$, we can conclude $a=c$. That is, it doesn't send two different values to the same value. A function $f:A\to B$ is "onto" if every $b\in B$ has an $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$ - that is, the range of $f$ is all of $B$. Two sets have the same cardinality of there is a bijection between them - a bijection is just a "one-to-one" and "onto" function.

Comment: Is it possible to do a proof of this not involving function mapping?